# How to convert Optional<Entity> to Optional<EntityDTO> in Spring JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, option-type

I am new in Spring and although I can convert domain entities as `List<Entity>`, I cannot convert them properly for the the `Optional<Entity>`. I have the following methods in repository and service:

***EmployeeRepository:***

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ...")
Optional<Employee> findByUuid(@Param(value = "uuid") final UUID uuid);
```

***EmployeeService:***

```
@Override
@LogExecution
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Optional<EmployeeDTO> findByUuid(UUID uuid) {
    Optional<Employee> employee = employeeRepository.findByUuid(uuid);
        return employee
                .stream()
                .map(EmployeeDTO::new)
                // .orElse(null);
                //.findFirst(); /// ??? 
    }
```

My questions:

**1.** How should I convert `Optional<Employee>` to `Optional<EmployeeDTO>` properly?

**2.** Does `Spring JPA` collect the fields in the `SELECT` clause and map them in the service method to the corresponding `DTO` by matching their names? If so, does it maintain the naming e.g. `employee_name` to `employeeName` in database table and domain model class?

Comment: If `EmployeeDTO`'s constructor accepts an `Employee` as an argument to build itself as your code seems to imply, than that's it. `map` returns an `Optional<EmployeeDTO>` there.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes, it accepts, but the code above throws incompatible return type. Required: `Optional <EmployeeDTO>` --> Provided: `Stream
<Object>`

Comment: Remove `.stream()` before `.map`, I didn't see it. You want `Optional`'s `map`, not `Stream`'s `map`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yess, exactly. What about my 2nd question?

Comment: Since [Spring Data already supports projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces), did you try `Optional<EmployeeDTO> findByUuid(...)`?

Comment: As for your 2nd question: Spring JPA does not do any mapping in your service, that code is totally up to you. Naming conventions need to handled by you in that case, i.e. Spring Data JPA only deals with the entities and tables. If your DTO contains differently named properties you'd have to map those yourself (you could use something like mapstruct to handle that but I'd recommend keeping property names in sync - and letting Spring Data actually return the DTOs directly).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks a lot for this good explanation. But I am wondering, when I use `@Query` and retrieve a cluster from multiple tables, how these fields from multiple tables are returned to service? In the example above, the return type of the repository method (`findByUuid`) is `Optional<Employee>` . But, it has some fields from other table (e.g. Country) that is retrieved by JOIN in the `Query()` >>>

Comment: >>> So, how Spring Data JPA converts these 2 table data to the Service method? Suppose that I join Employee and Country tables and get Id, EmployeeName, CountryId, CoutryName fields in the SELECT clause of `Query` parameter in the repository method.

Comment: Well, if you provide the columns to be selected then Spring could try to work its magic and map the columns to properties of an entity or projection by name and type (I'm not sure whether it wouldn't actually load the entire entity if you tell Spring to return one) but in case that's not possible (I actually didn't use the combination of `@Query` with column lists and entities or projections) Spring Data would probably do the same as plain JPA and just return a `List<Object[]>` where the arrays represent the row values.

Comment: When using `@Query()` it seem to be logical to return `List<Object[]>`, but the return type of the method seems to be domain entity (Employee). So, at this point I cannot understand how the fields from other table (e.g. Country) will be included or retrieved in the Service method if we pass Employee as shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping that happens between the output of `employeeRepository#findByUuid` that is `Optional<Employee>` and the method output type `Optional<EmployeeDTO>` is *1:1*, so no `Stream` (calling `stream()`) here is involved.

All you need is to map properly the fields of `Employee` into `EmployeeDTO`. Handling the case the `Optional` returned from the `employeeRepository#findByUuid` is actually empty could be left on the subsequent chains of the optional. There is no need for `orElse` or `findFirst` calls.

Assuming the following classes both with all-args constructor and getters:

```
class Employee {
    private final long id;
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
}
```

```
class EmployeeDTO {
    private final long id;
    private final String name;
    private final String surname;
}
```

... you can perform this. Nothing else than finding a way to create `EmployeeDTO` from `Employee`'s fields is needed. If the `Optional` returned from the `employeeRepository` is returned, no mapping happens and an empty `Optional` is returned.

```
@Override
@LogExecution
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public Optional<EmployeeDTO> findByUuid(UUID uuid) {
    return employeeRepository
        .findByUuid(uuid)                             // Optional<Employee>
        .map(emp -> new EmployeeDTO(                  // Optional<EmployeeDTO>
                 emp.getId(),                         // .. id -> id
                 emp.getFirstName(),                  // .. firstName -> name
                 emp.getLastName()));                 // .. lastName -> surname
}
```

Note: For `Employee` -> `EmployeeDTO` mapping I recommend picking one of these:

- Create a constructor accepting `Employee` in `EmployeeDTO` allowing to map with `.map(EmployeeDTO::new)` (drawback: creates a dependency).
- Just map with getters/setters.
- Use a mapping framework such as [MapStruct](https://mapstruct.org/) or any other.

Comment: Many thanks for your perfect explanations. In this scene, I think I can also use `.map(EmployeeDTO::new)` if `EmployeeDTO` accepts `Employee` as parameters. Is that true?

Comment: I think map with `getters/setters` is the last 3 lines in your code, is not it? If so, does it also create dependency as `.map(EmployeeDTO::new)` as well?

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: 1. I have removed the comment. 2. If there is a constructor `public EmployeeDTO(Employee employee)`, then you can map using `.map(EmployeeDTO::new)`. 3. Nope, with the getters/setters and all-args constructor, you must use the following: `.map(e -> new EmployeeDTO(e.getId(), e.getName()))` and with the no-args constructor this: `.map(e -> { EmployeeDTO dto = new EmployeeDTO(); dto.setId(e.getId()); dto.setName(e.getName()); return dto; })`.

Comment: **You rock!**. Perfect explanations, many thanks.

Comment: On the other hand, does the `getters/setters` approach you mentioned also creates a dependency as creating a constructor accepting Employee in EmployeeDTO as well?

Comment: @PeterLustig: I'd rather call it a strategical downvote from you, but whatever. See my edit carefully: 1. The passing `Employee` into the constructor of `EmployeeDTO` was included in my original answer (between the code snippets). 2. MapStruct is a well-known library and I use it in my projects. I also answer in the [tag:mapstruct]. Your statement I copy-paste from your answer is invalid. 3. The bottom of my answer is only a summary of the way the OP has which partially covers yours. Moreover, you **didn't** answer how to use `Optional` at all.

Comment: @PeterLustig Bot answers are really very useful and I always mark the most useful one for my question. Of course I would like to select both of them as answer, but unfortunately I can just select one of them. On the other hand, there is not any copy from any answer for this question that I keep attention on SO and downvote for such situation. As a result, the only problem is not being able to vote up your answer, but I can fix it if you vote up for my question :) Again, many thanks both of you.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis On the other hand, does the getters/setters approach you mentioned also creates a dependency as creating a constructor accepting Employee in EmployeeDTO as well?

Comment: I mentioned that. Please read both my answer and the edits before you rage-downvote it. I give you a chance to revert it and remove all the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options to map your entity to a DTO.

1. Using projections: Your repository can directly return a DTO by using projections. This might be the best option if you don't need the entity at all. You can find everything about projections here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections
2. Using a library like [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/) or [modelmapper](http://modelmapper.org/) to generate your mapping code
3. Add a constructor or static factory method to your DTO. Something like

```java
class EmployeeDTO {
   // fields here ...
   public static EmployeeDTO ofEntity(Employee entity) {
     var dto = new EmployeeDTO();
     // set fields
     return dto;
   }
}
```

And call `employee.map(EmployeeDTO::ofEntity)` in your service.

Comment: Does `employee.map(EmployeeDTO::ofEntity` in your code similar to `.map(EmployeeDTO::new)`? What is the difference?

Comment: I cannot vote up as I have not enough repo :(

Comment: Any reply please?

Comment: The difference is that `EmployeeDTO::new` calls the default constructor. In some cases you don't want to map all your entity fields to your DTO, so you only map the fields you need in your `ofEntity` static factory

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any vote up pls so that I can vote up your answer?